# Gray code in Matrix

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I have a matrix $m \times n$ with entry 0 or 1. Of course there is a possible $2^{m\times n}$ matrix. I want to sort all the matrices so that every two consecutive matrices are only 1 bit different, and the different ones must be neighboring. I can make the first 2 matrices arbitrarily, but the next matrix will depend on the previous matrix. For example 2 initial matrix is

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

The changed bit is $a_{22}$ from 0 to 1. The third possible matrix is

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Because neighbors $a_{22}$ are $a_{12}$ and $a_{21}$. Can not change $a_{11}$ because it is not neighboring $a_{22}$

I can use dynamic programming, but complexity problems will arise if $m, n$ is large enough. Is there maybe a better algorithm? Or special case?

This is one of examples output for $m = n = 2$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Can you please argue that it is always possible for general $m, n$ to have "consecutive change positions" differ by one column only *or* one row, only (even "allowing wraparound": for a 3×3 matrix, $a_{21}$ and $a_{23}$ would be  neighbours, too).

Comment: @greybeard tbh i can't guarantee it. Yes you're right $a_{21}$ and $a_{23}$ are neighbors of $a_{22}$ in 3×3 matrix

Comment: `a₂₁ and a₂₃ are neighbors of a₂₂` I tried to get at $a_{21}$ and $a_{23}$ being neighbours *to each other* (so every element has four neighbours, including "corner elements" like $a_{11}$.

Comment: @greybeard corner element has two neighbors. Edge element has three neighbors. a_12 and a_21 are the only neighbors of a_11

Comment: Have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code)? It mentions many different Gray codes with various properties.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I've checked it. But still have no idea